# OS X with Python: Dynamic module not initialized properly

Tags: macos, python-2.7, caffe, pycaffe

I'm having some problems when trying to execute the pycaffe:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 520, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 453, in get_config_vars
    import re
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 108, in <module>
    import _locale
SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly
```

I have read about it and it seems to be something related with Python linking (I am using the Homebrew one).